# Why I can't use service (instead of activity) as a default assist?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to make a simple service that handles ASSIST intents but doesn't have any UI, it just issues a http request when it is triggered and closes. But when I define intent filter it doesn't show up in default assist app menu:

```
    <service android:name=".IntentProcessor">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

If I do the same for activity it works. What is the difference? Should I use some kind of hidden activity instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference?

`ACTION_ASSIST` is [documented to be an activity action](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_ASSIST).

When the system goes looking for assistants, it will use `queryIntentActivities()`. When it goes to start an assistant, it will use `startActivity()`.

> Should I use some kind of hidden activity instead?

It will need to be an activity of some form. Whether it is "hidden" or not will depend on whether your users are expecting visual feedback or not.